# Meaning of * in argument position

Tags: ruby, splat

Assume `arr` is an array `[[1,3],[2,5],[3,8]]`. I was wondering what `*` means. What does it mean?

```
hash = Hash[*arr.flatten] # => {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>8}
```

I tried the following

```
arr.flatten # => [1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]
Hash[arr.flatten] # => {}
Hash[*a.flatten] # => {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>8}
```

Comment: If you have trouble remembering what "splat" does, visualize a teenage boy eying a mustard packet on the floor at McDonald's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation

When you do `array.flatten` it will give you one *flatten array* where all inner array slatted. Now You are putting this *flatten array* inside the [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method. But `Hash::[]` supports the below constructs :

```
Hash[ key, value, ... ] → new_hash 
# or
Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ] → new_hash
```

Now `array.flatten` gives you `[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]`. Now you are putting this array inside `Hash[]` like `Hash[[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]]`. Now compare with the above 2 structures. Does either of them match ? *NO*. So you need to splat the inner array again, thus it need (splatted operator)`*` to splat the inner array.

Now you did `Hash[*[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]]`, which gives `Hash[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]`. Now again check from the above 2 constructs. Does it match with either of the 2 ? This time *YES*, first one. So you got the desired hash `{1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>8}`.

BTW, you don't need to splat, as the second construt exactly matched when you put *array* inside `Hash::[]` directly.

```
array = [[1,3],[2,5],[3,8]]
Hash[array] # => {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>8}
```

The above worked, because `Hash[array]` means `Hash[[[1,3],[2,5],[3,8]]]`, which *exactly the second structure* as documentation suggested.

Read [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22splat%22) to see how *splatting* work in Ruby.

There is another construct :-

```
 Hash[ object ] → new_hash
```

This I think is also important to tell you why you got `{}`. `Hash[[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]]` same as the last type of construct as per the doc. The doc is saying -

> The second and *third form take a single argument* which is either an array of key-value pairs or *an object convertible to a hash.*

So. `[1,3,2,5,3,8]` it is an `Array` object *not convertible* to `Hash`. Currently it is giving you an *empty hash*, if an *object* as per the third construct. But it will throw error in future version of release. See Below *warnings*.

```
[1] pry(main)> Hash[[1,2]]
(pry):1: warning: wrong element type Fixnum at 0 (expected array)
(pry):1: warning: ignoring wrong elements is deprecated, remove them explicitly
(pry):1: warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release
(pry):1: warning: wrong element type Fixnum at 1 (expected array)
(pry):1: warning: ignoring wrong elements is deprecated, remove them explicitly
(pry):1: warning: this causes ArgumentError in the next release
=> {}
```

My Ruby version is :

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: a little confusing .. so with ur logic are you saying Hash[*[array.faltten]] == Hash[*array.faltten] ?

Comment: Just to be clear, `splat` means `*`, and more can be read about what it does here http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument to the Hash class you can put it in parentheses...

```
Hash(arr.flatten)
```

or without...

```
Hash arr.flatten
```

In either case, Hash takes the argument and if it's an array with an even number of elements, it will create a hash where the odd elements are the keys and the even elements are the values.

Hash can also take square brackets to preform a similar operation

```
Hash[1, 2]
=> {1=>2}
```

BUT, when you do this...

```
Hash[arr.flatten]
```

You are passing the array WITHIN the array so you're getting unexpected results.

When you do this...

```
Hash[*arr.flatten]
```

You are saying take the array `arr.flatten` and pass it, not as an array, but as individual separate arguments to the method.

So where `Hash[arr.flatten]` is actually `Hash[[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]]` (an array containing one element which is an array) instead `Hash[*arr.flatten]` is actually `Hash[1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8]`(an array containing six elements)

Interestingly enough, the [] method can take an array containing arrays of key, value pairs so..

```
Hash[arr]
```

Works fine!  You don't have to flatten or splat anything.